# Some notation in definition of smooth morphism between schemes.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, Defitnion 6.14 and I'm confused about some notation :

[image]

What ${\partial {f_i}\over \partial {T_j}} (x)$ does exactly means?

As he remarked below, for $g = {\partial f_i \over \partial T_j} \in R[T_1, \cdots, T_n]$ and for $x \in \mathbb{A}^n_R$, $g(x) \in \kappa(x)$ is defined by the image of $g\in R[T_1, \cdots, T_n] = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n_R}(\mathbb{A}^n_R)$ in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{A}^n_{R,x}} / \mathbb{m}_x =: \kappa(x)$.

And in the above definition 6.14 - (1), $x$ is an element of $x \in U \subset X$ , not necesarilly in $\mathbb{A}^n_R$. This is point that I confused. I'am confused about the notation ${\partial {f_i}\over \partial {T_j}} (x)$. In fact, ${\partial {f_i}\over \partial {T_j}} (x)$ is, more correctly,
${\partial {f_i}\over \partial {T_j}} (l(j(x)))$, where $l : \operatorname{Spec}R[T_1, \cdots ,T_n]/(f_1, \cdots ,f_{n-d}) \to \operatorname{Spec}R[T_1 \cdots T_n]$ ?

Comment: Yes. It is standard to abuse $x$ vs. $j(x)$.

Comment: Yes. O.K. Thank you~